# TypeScript and ReactDOM.render method doesn't accept component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-dom, tsx

### TL;DR

I'm using TypeScript and React. I've defined my `AppContainer.tsx` component, exported it as default. I'm consuming this in the file `app.ts` where `ReactDOM` lives to render it to the targetted dom element. But there I receive the following errors (see image). **Read below for more information and links to GitHub repo.**

[image]

**Question:** What am I doing, or interpreting, wrong? From all code examples I've seen this should work - but maybe (clearly) I'm missing something. **Below is more info and links to the full GitHub repo**.

---

### Environment

- react 15.4.2
- react-dom 15.4.2
- typings: https://github.com/aredfox/electron-starter/blob/master/typings.json
- tsconfig: https://github.com/aredfox/electron-starter/blob/master/tsconfig.json

### Code

#### File '/components/AppContainer.tsx'

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts" />

// Top level application component

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/** IMPORTS **/
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*///*/

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/** COMPONENT **/
export default class AppContainer extends React.Component<{}, {}> {    
    render() {
        return ( <div /> );
    }    
}        
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*///*/
```

https://github.com/aredfox/electron-starter/blob/master/src/views/components/AppContainer.tsx

#### File 'app.ts'

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="interfaces.d.ts" />

// Setting up react inside the host html

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/** IMPORTS **/
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// Components
import AppContainer from './components/AppContainer';
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*///*/

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/** RENDER TO DOM **/
ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer/>,
    document.getElementById('AppContainer')
);
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*///*/
```

https://github.com/aredfox/electron-starter/blob/master/src/views/app.ts

### Quick Links

- Git repo: https://github.com/aredfox/electron-starter

  - `app.ts` file https://github.com/aredfox/electron-starter/blob/master/src/views/app.ts
  - `AppContainer.tsx` file https://github.com/aredfox/electron-starter/blob/master/src/views/components/AppContainer.tsx

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can't use `jsx`/`tsx` syntax inside files which have `ts` extension.

You can either rename your file to `app.tsx`, or you can use [React.createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

```
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(AppContainer),
    document.getElementById('AppContainer')
);
```

Comment: To add to this... tsx is compiled to jsx, then to js, whereas .ts are compiled to .js. Your tsconfig.json should also have a property "jsx": "react".

Comment: Thanks A LOT! This was indeed what I was looking for.. How on earth could I overlook this...

Comment: I spent 2h figuring out this. Thanks a lot!