# What's the proper way of using ReactDomServer.renderToString with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering

I'm working on a Typescript app that does server-side rendering and I'm having trouble understanding the usage of `ReactDomServer.renderToString` and `ReactDom.hydrate`, specifically the type of arguments they sould receive.

I've found several examples (using JS) passing a JSX tag as the argument the following way:

```js
ReactDomServer.renderToString(<ExampleComponent exampleProp="anyValue" />);
```

But when I try this on Typescript I get the following error:

> Conversion of type 'RegExp' to type 'ExampleComponent' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

The way I got it working is by invoking `React.createElement` on my Component:

```js
ReactDomServer.renderToString(
  React.createElement(ExampleComponent, {exampleProp: anyValue})
)
```

Do you have to call `React.createElement` on the component you want to render (if so, why)? Or is it a bug/misconfiguration on my side?

Comment: I think this is one of the few ways to do SSR React with Typescript. According to this [medium post](https://medium.com/atticus-engineering/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-typescript-8cebb4400b3c) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41897800/1514049).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My problem was that the file extension was `.ts` and it needed to be `.tsx` for typescript to properly compile JSX.

Comment: is it OK to use .tsx files on the server?

Comment: @Yilmaz just as much as it is to use `.ts`. All of that is compiled at the end :)