# How can I use JS React Components in an existing TypeScript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

At hand I have an existing TypeScript project built without web components and I have a couple of React.js components in js files. Furthermore I'm using Webpack with a ts-loader only for my ts files.
I wonder what I need to do to instantiate these components in my existing code.
I noticed that I can't simply call `ReactDOM.render` because of the JSX syntax it uses.
So what would be a possibility to approach this and what do I have to add to do to get it through a Webpack bundler?

I'm also looking forward to someone helping me in case this might possibly be a duplicate. ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897420/typescript-and-reactdom-render-method-doesnt-accept-component

Comment: this solution will answer your query i guess

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!